# handlebars helper: not passing variable

Tags: marionette, handlebars.js, brunch

Im using Brunch and I added a custom helper. This works great in normal view templates but in compositeView's itemView template the variable passed to helper is undefined. Without a helper the template is compiled fine.

```
// Helper
Handlebars.registerHelper 'mny', (val) ->
    val.toString().replace( /\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " " )

// Example
{{price}} //it works
{{mny price}} //it doesn't
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handlebars needs to know its a function so put a `#` in front of mny

```
{{#mny price}}
```

hope that fixes it for you